# Python Package Index recursive package dependency resolver

Tags: perl

My work has an isolated network that developers write applications to run inside of. These developers often write Python code. This Python code often requires modules from the Python Package Index (PyPi) to be downloaded using something like pip. In order to allow these developers to run their software on this isolated network, I need to provide them with a PyPi mirror so they can get the modules their software depends upon. To accomplish this, I setup a [bandersnatch](https://github.com/pypa/bandersnatch/) mirror on a VM in my DMZ and configured our VMs to use this mirror instead of the (unreachable from their perspective) internet. So far, so good.

Policy dictates that software coming into our isolated network must be approved first, meaning I cannot simply do a full mirror of the entire Python Package Index (if I even had the disk space for such a thing... I'm not sure I do) and let people have whatever they want. Bandersnatch supports this no problem; by including this in it's config file, I essentially have a list of ONLY the approved packages that will show up on the mirror:

```
 [allowlist]
 packages =
    absl-py
    astunparse
    caproto
    confluent_kafka
    ConfigArgParse
    ess-streaming-data-types
    flatbuffers
    gast
    gpytorch
    ...<and so on>...
```

Unfortunately, Bandersnatch does not do any dependency resolution on this list of packages to allow mirroring of and [it does not seem likely they will implement that feature](https://github.com/pypa/bandersnatch/issues/110). It does not seem any other PyPi mirror servers are setup to allow this either, but if I have missed something, please let me know.

So I find myself having a list of Python Packages that I need to know all of their dependencies of, recursively, so I can mirror that whole list. I am not a Python programmer, so I wrote it in Perl. I think it works, but I'd really appreciate another set of eyes on it.

My Code: https://pastebin.com/hR6Yru4W

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# This script is a (probably naive) attempt at writing a recursive dependency resolver for the Python package index (PyPi)
# A list of (space seperated) Python Package names provided on the command line are the starting point
# Each package in that list is added to a graph, then every node(vertex) in that graph has edges defined between the node itself
# and each of it's dependencies (which become their own nodes as a result)
# Every node in the graph is iterated through, has it's dependencies(edges) defined, and the process is repeated until 
# the graph stops changing. Once there are no more dependencies to find, it prints out a (alphabetically sorted) list
# of every package that would be required to install every package given as an argument to this script. Note that this list
# WILL INCLUDE the packages that were initially provided as part of the list.

use JSON;
use Graph;

# Our main dependency graph objects
# We need two so we can check if the graph changed between dependency runs
# When the two graphs stay the same after a dependency run, we know our graph is complete
my $Agraph = Graph->new();
my $Bgraph = Graph->new();

# Accepts a list of python packages to check dependencies for
# Returns a list of python packages the arguments depend upon
# Note that this function is NOT RECURSIVE. It ONLY provides the direct dependencies.
sub get_deps {
    my $ret = [];
    my $json = JSON->new;
    foreach my $package ( @_ ) {
        my $curl = `curl -s "https://pypi.org/pypi/$package/json"`;
        my $reqs = $json->decode($curl)->{info}->{requires_dist};
        if (defined($reqs)) {
            foreach my $dep (@$reqs) {
                $dep =~ s/[^a-zA-Z0-9-].*$//;
                push(@$ret, $dep);
            }
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}

# @ARGV is a list of packages we need to find all dependencies for and is the roots of our dependency graph
foreach my $package (@ARGV) {
    $Agraph->add_vertex($package);
}

# A list of packages we have already gotten dependnecies for so we don't check twice
my $checked = [];

# Loop until our graphs stop changing between dependency runs
while ( $Agraph ne $Bgraph ) {
    $Bgraph = $Agraph->deep_copy();

    # Check every single vertice in our graph
    my @vertlist = $Agraph->vertices;
    foreach my $package (@vertlist) {
        # If we haven't checked this package before, get it added to the graph with all of it's dependencies
        if (! grep( /^$package$/, @$checked )) {
            my $deplist = get_deps($package);
            foreach my $dep (@$deplist) {
                $Agraph->add_edge($package, $dep);
            }
            # Add this package to our list of already checked packages so we don't waste time
            push(@$checked, $package);
        }
    }
}

my @fulldeplist = sort $Agraph->vertices;
foreach my $package (@fulldeplist) {
    print "$package\n";
}
```

Comment: As a supplement, consider using https://pypi.org/project/pip-tools/ `pip-compile` to translate a collection of required packages `requirements.in` into a full list including their dependencies `requirements.txt`. This tool will do all of the graph resolution for you, including resolving specific compatible versions for every package.

Comment: Ah... I wasn't aware pip-compile would take an arbitrary list of packages (in a text file) into a full list with depedencies like this. This could have saved me a ton of time, thank you! One thing I'm a little concerned about is that my dependency resolver produces SIGNIFICANTLY more results for even simple test cases. Feeding pip-compile _just_ tensorflow produces a list 44 entries long. Feeding the same single package to my script produces a list over 2000 entries long.

Comment: I have not run your script to check it myself, but it could be that the `requires_dist` field might include more than just the runtime packages you would care about. Looking at https://pypi.org/pypi/pip-tools/json for example I can see a lot of packages that are only needed for someone testing the package, which would not be necessary for you to simply use the package. If you take that to the extreme I could easily see your package list blowing up as you grab every test and non-prod package for every transitive dependency in the tree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The layout of the code is very good, with nice use of vertical whitespace and consistent indentation.  It also makes good use of comments.  It is great that you used `strict` and `warnings`.

In the `grep` line, it would be a good idea to use `\Q` and `\E` to escape any potential regular expression metacharacters that might be in your `$package` variable.  See also [quotemeta](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta)

The remaining suggestions are mostly for good coding style, and some are my personal preference.

When I `use` modules like `JSON`, I like to only import what is being used by the code so as to not clutter up the namespace.  In your case, since you use the object-oriented interface, you can specify an empty list; I'll show this below.

When I have header comments, I like to place them inside Perl [POD](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod) (`=head`, etc.).  This provides a command-line manpage for you when you use the [perldoc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldoc) command:

```
perldoc script.pl
```

When dereferencing an array reference, I prefer to use extra braces:

```
@{ $ret }
```

Refer to this [perlcritic](https://metacpan.org/dist/Perl-Critic/view/bin/perlcritic) policy for further details: [Perl::Critic::Policy::References::ProhibitDoubleSigil](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Critic::Policy::References::ProhibitDoubleSigils).

Since backticks (``` `` ```) can be easily missed, I prefer to use the [qx](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/qx) quoting operator; it stands out more in the code.

Here is the code with modifications.  I also ran your code through a spell checker and fixed some typos in your comments (`dependnecies`, `seperated`).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

=head1 Description

 This script is a (probably naive) attempt at writing a recursive dependency resolver for the Python package index (PyPi)
 A list of (space separated) Python Package names provided on the command line are the starting point
 Each package in that list is added to a graph, then every node(vertex) in that graph has edges defined between the node itself
 and each of it's dependencies (which become their own nodes as a result)
 Every node in the graph is iterated through, has it's dependencies(edges) defined, and the process is repeated until 
 the graph stops changing. Once there are no more dependencies to find, it prints out a (alphabetically sorted) list
 of every package that would be required to install every package given as an argument to this script. Note that this list
 WILL INCLUDE the packages that were initially provided as part of the list.

=cut

use JSON  qw();
use Graph qw();

# Our main dependency graph objects
# We need two so we can check if the graph changed between dependency runs
# When the two graphs stay the same after a dependency run, we know our graph is complete
my $Agraph = Graph->new();
my $Bgraph = Graph->new();

# Accepts a list of python packages to check dependencies for
# Returns a list of python packages the arguments depend upon
# Note that this function is NOT RECURSIVE. It ONLY provides the direct dependencies.
sub get_deps {
    my $ret = [];
    my $json = JSON->new;
    foreach my $package ( @_ ) {
        my $curl = qx(curl -s "https://pypi.org/pypi/$package/json");
        my $reqs = $json->decode($curl)->{info}->{requires_dist};
        if (defined($reqs)) {
            foreach my $dep (@{ $reqs }) {
                $dep =~ s/[^a-zA-Z0-9-].*$//;
                push(@{ $ret }, $dep);
            }
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}

# @ARGV is a list of packages we need to find all dependencies for and is the roots of our dependency graph
foreach my $package (@ARGV) {
    $Agraph->add_vertex($package);
}

# A list of packages we have already gotten dependencies for so we don't check twice
my $checked = [];

# Loop until our graphs stop changing between dependency runs
while ( $Agraph ne $Bgraph ) {
    $Bgraph = $Agraph->deep_copy();

    # Check every single vertice in our graph
    my @vertlist = $Agraph->vertices;
    foreach my $package (@vertlist) {
        # If we haven't checked this package before, get it added to the graph with all of it's dependencies
        if (! grep( /^\Q$package\E$/, @{ $checked } )) {
            my $deplist = get_deps($package);
            foreach my $dep (@{ $deplist }) {
                $Agraph->add_edge($package, $dep);
            }
            # Add this package to our list of already checked packages so we don't waste time
            push(@{ $checked }, $package);
        }
    }
}

my @fulldeplist = sort $Agraph->vertices;
foreach my $package (@fulldeplist) {
    print "$package\n";
}
```

---

I like to use this line for `warnings`, but it can be too restrictive for some people's tastes:

```
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
```

[FATAL](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=931025)

Answer (score 0):

Python's PIP with a "virtual environment" could, I suspect, be used to follow the dependencies to create a set of directories which could be then reviewed before being copied to your "walled garden".

This would prevent the need for your developers to install anything (they would automatically get all approved libraries) but would only work if the libraries were cross compatible.

The main advantage is if you wished to review the library code before it is copied to your stand alone environment.  It might also be advantageous in teasing out some cross package incompatibilities if the developed applications had to work together.